# Flickr API Error, Json callback

Tags: jquery, json, api, flickr

why I have this kind of error in my code :

**"Error: jsonFlickrApi is not defined"**

```
    $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=669158895706254986e97354a3c7e9a9&photoset_id=72157623477817483&extras=original_format&format=json&jsoncallback;=?',
    function(data){
        var classShown = 'class="lightbox"';
        var classHidden = 'class="lightbox hidden"';


        $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, rPhoto){
            var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + rPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
                + rPhoto.server + '/' + rPhoto.id + '_' + rPhoto.secret;
......
```

there are syme issues in JSON datatype or something else, suggest me how to fix it , pls

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The end of your URL is a bit off, this:

```
....&jsoncallback;=?
```

Should be:

```
....&jsoncallback=?
```

jQuery fills in this method on it's own with a dynamically named function (your `function(data)` is converted to this named function or JSONP to work).  Since the format's off it's not replacing this correctly and the *default* method is `jsonFlickrApi`.

If you visit the [url directly](http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=669158895706254986e97354a3c7e9a9&photoset_id=72157623477817483&extras=original_format&format=json) (this is without the callback) you'll see it looks like this:

```
jsonFlickrApi({ ... })
```

If you *do* provide a callback ([like this url](http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=669158895706254986e97354a3c7e9a9&photoset_id=72157623477817483&extras=original_format&format=json&jsoncallback=myFunction)), it looks like this:

```
myFunction({ ... })
```

This is what jQuery *should* do, but due to the malformed URL it isn't replacing the `?`, fix it and it'll do that, and it'll call the proper method, instead of the default one.